# How do I say "Welcome to our fun little group?"

Tags: traduction, anglais

How do I say "Welcome to our fun little group?"  I want to ensure that I am saying it correctly.  It's been a long time since I have used my French!

Comment: Hello! Can you Please provide more insights on the composition of this "fun little group"

Comment: It is a Facebook group and this person is from France so I would like to properly welcome him en Francais!  I just don't use the language where I am.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> Bienvenue dans notre petit groupe sympa !

"sympa" is a short French word for *sympathique* : nice, like in "Nice to meet you", with something very pleasant.

Answer (score 4):

Bienvenue dans notre sympathique petit groupe !

Answer (score 0):

You can say : Bienvenue dans notre petit groupe amusant!

Comment: Good, if you could select my answer as the winning one it would be nice. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If saying welcome to more than one person, would it be Bienvenus?  Like Bienvenidos in Spanish?  And is the e for a female person only?  Bienvenu for a male person?  Merci!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/21970)